# How to check absence of data (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Basically this is a reporting system, where user report their activity daily so I want to check for users who don't report their daily activity.

I join 2 tables with this query to check for people who report in a certain date

```
SELECT DISTINCT Report.InputDate, User.ID, User.Name
FROM User JOIN Report on User.ID = Report.ID 
WHERE Report.InputDate BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-04'
ORDER BY Report.InputDate
```

So if someone didn't report at 2014-02-02 the result will be:

```
2014-02-01 | Guy | 01 |
2014-02-03 | Guy | 01 |
```

What I'm looking for is how to check for the people that **didn't report** at the range of date in the query, so the result will be:

```
2014-02-02 | Guy | 01 |
```

(And if possible, it will display a row with a date where no one even report, so if no one report at 2014-02-01 the result will be):

```
2014-02-01 |  |  |
```

***update**

Let's say the columns in table User are: ID, Name

Columns in table Report are: ID, InputDate

And there is another table, ReportDetail that has columns: ID, ActivityType

Comment: please give us the query to create the source tables and also to insert a few sample rows in it. If you need help, you have to make it easy for others to help you. Chenqui.

Comment: You are saying `How to check the other way around`? but `2014-02-02` is also in between the dates you mention? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev actually it is a large database that is not made by me so I made the question simple as that. Basically it is a reporting system, where user report their activity daily so I want to check for users who don't report their activity. There are 3 tables, User table for users' data, ReportDetail table for the detailed reports, and Report table for the relation between two.

Comment: @NickyvV 2014-02-02 is the example of a successful query which I am looking for, and it is not displayed with my query, please re-check.

Answer (score 0):

Try Executing this

```
SELECT DISTINCT Report.InputDate, User.NIMK, User.NamaLengkap
FROM User JOIN Report on User.ID = Report.ID 
WHERE not (Report.InputDate  between '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-04')
ORDER BY Report.InputDate
```

Comment: It is not I'm looking for. It displays the reports that in other dates.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need list of each date status(present or absence)

```
Declare @startdate date='2014-02-01' 
Declare @enddate date= '2014-02-04'

;with cte as
(Select @startdate as dt
union all
select DATEADD(day,1,dt) dt from cte a 

where  DATEADD(day,1,dt) <=@enddate )
,cte1 as
(
SELECT DISTINCT Report.InputDate, User.NIMK, User.NamaLengkap
FROM User JOIN Report on User.ID = Report.ID 
WHERE Report.InputDate BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-04'

)
--select dt from cte --check this one
select  * from cte a left join cte1 b on a.dt=b.InputDate -- correct this yourself
```

Comment: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: And if I remove ORDER BY: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
The multi-part identifier "User.ID" could not be bound.

Comment: @user3282706 first run this "select dt from cte " then you see yourself that how you can join cte and cte1 using left join.Or you provide sample data